# Accept not waiting for new connections

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on this calendar/reminders server-client thing. I've stumbled across a bug where I may have misunderstood the behaviour of the `accept()` function while trying to handle new connections.

The client basically specifies a day to view and sends it to the server, then gets some text back and closes the connection.(I have been using telnet and netcat to test this so far though.) 
After I hit ctrl+d on netcat after I send the command and receive the message, the server gets and infinite output loop of "New connection\n".

The way I understood `accept()` was that when it is called, it sets the left hand side to a socket descriptor for a connection on the `listen()` backlog, or waits until there is a connection before returning. So either I am mistaken or I am doing something wrong:

```c
bind(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

listen(client_socket, 5);



//start main loop. first level checks for commands
while (1)
{
  client_socket = accept(client_socket, NULL, NULL);
  printf("New connection.\n");

  recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

  /*Bunch of code here that interprets what was sent with some string manipulation 
  and serves back parts of a text file. No socket functions other than send() twice here*/

  recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

}
```

The idea I had in mind was, once the job is done, wait until the client closes the connection, which sends a message of length 0(hence the `recv()` at the end), then loop back to the `accept()` which accepts or waits for the next connection. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is accept returning -1. If it is check errno to find out what the error is.

Comment: ```printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));``` returns "Invalid argument"

Comment: `client_socket = accept(client_socket, NULL, NULL);` You don't see anything funny about that line?

Comment: Well looks like the fd you are passing to accept is invalid,  which probably indicates an error further up. Always check return codes.

Comment: Is it because I'm trying to set client_socket to the accept of client_socket? Is that not a thing you can do twice?

Comment: You need two socket variables, one for the listening socket and one for the accepted socket. The listening socket doesn't have anything to do with clients. But there is no such thing in TCP as a message of length zero. You can't send it and you can't receive it. So you could block forever in the final `recv()`. There is also  no apparent reason why you need to wait for one even if there was such a thing. Just close the accepted client socket when you're done with it, and make sure the client does the same. You also need to add some elementary error checking to this code, for every system call.

Comment: And you can't write correct networking code without storing the result of `recv()` into a variable. You have to check for zero and for -1, and if neither use it as the number of bytes returned.

Comment: Yes, I figured it would be something like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second call to `accept`, you are passing as the listening socket the descriptor for the first connection rather than the listening socket. You really need to check for errors on all these calls. Otherwise, your code will be impossible to debug.

```
  client_socket = accept(client_socket, NULL, NULL);
```

This is fine the first time. But it leaks the descriptor for the listening socket. So you can't accept another connection.

Comment: So it isn't really 'fine the first time' at all.

Comment: Not really, since it's a socket leak. But it works the first time.